# Spamassassin on 1and1 dedicated server

Tags: spamassassin, 1and1

I have a dedicated server on 1and1. When I send a mail from myself I get my mail like SPAM. The headers of the mail are:

> 1.0 EXTRA_MPART_TYPE Header has extraneous Content-type:...type= entry
> 3.1 FH_HOST_EQ_DYNAMICIP Host is dynamicip
> 0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
> 2.4 HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_08 BODY: HTML: images with 400-800 bytes of words
> 0.5 RCVD_IN_PBL RBL: Received via a relay in Spamhaus PBL [81.37.108.61 listed in zen.spamhaus.org]
> 1.6 RCVD_IN_SORBS_DUL RBL: SORBS: sent directly from dynamic IP address [81.37.108.61 listed in dnsbl.sorbs.net]
> 0.1 RDNS_DYNAMIC Delivered to trusted network by host with dynamic-looking rDNS
> 1.1 HTML_SHORT_LINK_IMG_1 HTML is very short with a linked image
> 0.7 SHORT_HELO_AND_INLINE_IMAGE Short HELO string, with inline image
> 3.0 DOS_OE_TO_MX_IMAGE Direct to MX with OE headers and an image
> 0.0 DYN_RDNS_SHORT_HELO_IMAGE Short HELO string, dynamic rDNS, inline image
> 0.3 DYN_RDNS_SHORT_HELO_HTML Sent by dynamic rDNS, short HELO, and HTML
> 0.0 DYN_RDNS_AND_INLINE_IMAGE Contains image, and was sent by dynamic rDNS
> -1.4 AWL AWL: From: address is in the auto white-list

The IP is in a black list, but I have a dynamic IP from my ISP (Telefónica). What can I do?

Also I get this error: DOS_OE_TO_MX_IMAGE. This error only occurs with Outlook. How can I solve it? I tried to put the image externally and I get DOS_OE_TO_MX instead DOS_OE_TO_MX_IMAGE

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Your major problems & their solutions:

- `FH_HOST_EQ_DYNAMICIP` + `RCVD_IN_PBL RBL` + `RCVD_IN_SORBS_DUL RBL`

  - Your IP is not supposed to be sending email to the internet on its own (According to your ISP's policy and SA's preconceptions about dynamic IPs). Use Telefonica's SMTP server to relay your mail.
- `DOS_OE_TO_MX` / `DOS_OE_TO_MX_IMAGE`

  - Your email is being sent from Outlook Express (and has an image in it): It smells of spam.  It will smell less spammy if you use Telefonica's SMTP server since it won't be "direct to MX" anymore.
- `HTML_IMAGE_ONLY_08 BODY`

  - Your email is "mostly pictures": It smells of spam. Use more words or fewer pictures :)

---

You can also set up SMTP Auth and exempt authenticated connections from SpamAssassin filtering if you really can't use Telefonica's servers to relay. (Implementation of this is MTA dependent and left as an exercise for the reader.)